# Using a C string like a FILE*

Tags: c, file-pointer

I have a C function that reads a stream of characters from a `FILE*`.

How might I create a `FILE*` from a string in this situation?

Edit:

I think my original post may have been misleading. I want to create a `FILE*` from a literal string value, so that the resulting `FILE*` would behave as though there really was a file somewhere that contains the string without actually creating a file.

The following is what I would like to do:

```
void parse(FILE* f, Element* result);

int main(int argc, char** argv){
    FILE* f = mysteryFunc("hello world!");
    Element result;
    parse(f,&result);
}
```

Comment: You mean like calling "FILE* file = fopen("somefilename.txt", "r");"

Comment: C's standard library doesn't provide that capability.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Standard C provides no such facility, but POSIX defines the [`fmemopen()`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fmemopen.3.html) function that does exactly what you want.

Comment: `libcurl` needs a `FILE*` and so I used this trick to create a `FILE*` from a `std::string` and then called successfully `curl_easy_setopt(curl_handle, CURLOPT_READDATA, file_pointer);`.

Answer (score 10):

Unfortunately, C's standard library doesn't provide this functionality; but there are a few ways to get around it:

- Create a temporary file, write your string to it, then open it for reading. If you've got POSIX, `gettempnam` will choose a unique name for you
- The other option (again for POSIX only) is to `fork` a new process, whose job will be to `write` the string to a pipe, while you `fdopen` the other end to obtain a `FILE*` for your function.
- As @KeithThompson pointed out, `fmemopen` does exactily what you want, so if you have POSIX, use that. On any other platform, (unless you can find the platform-equivalent), you'll need a temporary file.

Answer (score 3):

Last time I had this kind of problem I actually created a pipe, launched a thread, and used the thread to write the data into the pipe... you would have to look into operating system calls, though.

There are probably other ways, like creating a memory mapped file, but I was looking for something that just worked without a lot of work and research.

EDIT: you can, of course, change the problem to "how do I find a nice temporary filename". Then you could write the data to a file, and read it back in :-)

Answer (score 2):

```
pid_t pid;
int pipeIDs[2];

if (pipe (pipeIDs)) {
   fprintf (stderr, "ERROR, cannot create pipe.\n");
   return EXIT_FAILURE;
} 

pid = fork ();
if (pid == (pid_t) 0) {
   /* Write to PIPE in this THREAD  */

   FILE * file = fdopen( pipe[1], 'w');

   fprintf( file, "Hello world");
   return EXIT_SUCCESS;

} else if (pid < (pid_t) 0) {
  fprintf (stderr, "ERROR, cannot create thread.\n");
  return EXIT_FAILURE;
}


FILE* myFile = fdopen(pipe[0], 'r');

// DONE! You can read the string from myFile

....  .....
```

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you can change the code a little bit to receive a custom handle.

```
void parse(my_handle *h, Element *result)
{
  // read from handle and process
  // call h->read instead of fread
}
```

and defines the handle like this:

```
struct my_handle
{
    // wrapper for fread or something
    int (*read)(struct my_handle *h, char *buffer, int readsize);
    // maybe some more methods you need
};
```

implement your FILE* wrapper

```
struct my_file_handle
{
    struct my_handle base;
    FILE *fp;
};

int read_from_file(struct my_handle *h, char *buffer, int readsize)
{
    return fread(buffer, 1, readsize, ((my_file_handle*)h)->fp);
}

// function to init the FILE* wrapper
void init_my_file_handle(struct my_file_handle *h, FILE *fp)
{
    h->base.read = read_from_file;
    h->fp = fp;
}
```

Now, implement your string reader

```
struct my_string_handle
{
    struct my_handle base;
    // string buffer, size, and current position
    const char *buffer;
    int size;
    int position;
};

// string reader
int read_from_string(struct my_handle *h, char *buffer, int readsize)
{
    // implement it yourself. It's easy.
}

// create string reader handle
void init_my_string_handle(struct my_string_handle *h, const char *str, int strsize)
{
    // i think you know how to init it now.
}
```

//////////////////////////////////////////////////

And now, you can simply send a handle to your parse function. The function doesn't care where the data comes from, it can even read data from network!

Answer (score 0):

### This is an old question, but deserves a better answer.

C has *always* had the ability to read and write strings using the formatted I/O functions. You just need to keep track of where you are in the string!

#### Reading a string

To read a string you need the `%n` format string specifier, which returns the number of bytes read each time we use `sscanf()`. Here is a simple example with a loop:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
  const char * s = "2 3 5 7";
  int n = 0;
  int value;
  while (sscanf( s+=n, "%d%n", &value, &n ) == 1)
  {
    printf( "value = %d\n", value );
  }
}
```

Another way to have written that loop would be:

```
for (int value, n;  sscanf( s, "%d%n", &value, &n ) == 1;  s += n)
```

Whichever floats your boat best.
The loop is not important.

What is important is that we increment the value of `s` after every read.

- Notice how we don’t bother to remember *original* value of `s` in this example? If it matters, use a temporary, as we do in our next example.
- It is also important that we *stop reading* when `sscanf` fails. This is the normal usage for the `scanf` family of functions.

#### Writing a string

In this case `sprintf()` helps us by directly returning the number of bytes written. Here’s a simple example of building a string using several formatted outputs:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
  char s[100] = {0};

  char * p = s;
  p += sprintf( p, "%d %s", 3, "three" );
  p += sprintf( p, "; " );
  p += sprintf( p, "%.2f %s", 3.141592, "pi" );
  *p = '\0'; // don’t forget it!
  
  printf( "s = \"%s\"\n", s );
  printf( "number of bytes written = %zu = %zu\n", p-s, strlen(s) );
}
```

The important points:

- This time we do not want to clobber `s` (and in this particular example couldn’t even if we wanted to), so we use a helper `p`.
- We cannot forget to *manually* add that null-terminator. (Which should make sense, since we are manually building the string.)
- **BUFFER OVERFLOW IS POSSIBLE**

That last point is significant, and a usual concern when building strings in C. As always, whether using `strcat()` or `sprintf()`, *always* make sure you have enough room to append everything you intend to write to your string!

###### Don’t use `%n` when writing

We *could have* used the `%n` specifier as well, but then we hit a cross-platform issue with MSVC: Microsoft targets `%n` and the `printf()` family of functions as a [security issue](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/set-printf-count-output). Whether or not you accept Microsoft’s reasoning you must live with the way things are.

If you are undeterred, you can add a little platform-specific code and use it anyway:

```
#ifdef _WIN32
_set_printf_count_output( 1 );
#endif

int n;
printf( "Hello%n world!", &n );
```

#### True FILE * I/O

Notice that we aren’t touching *actual* `FILE *` I/O functions, like `fgetc()`? If you need that, then you need an actual file.

[As mentioned above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11381745/2706707), use `tmpfile()` to open a temporary read/write file and use the usual `FILE *` I/O functions on it. Our read-a-string example could be re-written as:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
  FILE * f = tmpfile();
  if (!f) return 1;
  
  fprintf( f, "2 3 5 7" );
  rewind( f );
  
  int value;
  while (fscanf( f, "%d", &value ) == 1)
  {
    printf( "value = %d\n", value );
  }
  
  fclose( f );
}
```

This works just fine. Remember that `tmpfile()` might not give you an actual file on disk with a filename. You don’t need that anyway. In other words, it may very well be an in-memory buffer provided by the OS... which is kind of what this thread is about anyway, right?

Hopefully these options will give a deeper insight into the C standard I/O functions and their use. Next time you need to read or build a formatted string in parts, you will have a better grasp of the tools already provided for you.