# How to convert string to a FILE* opened for read

Tags: c++, c

I am writing a C++ application, which needs to call a library function that expects `FILE*` opened for read. I have no code of that function - it a black box to me.
The data that I need to pass to the function is in memory in `char*` buffer of a known size. Ideally, I need to wrap a my buffer in a `FILE*` structure and pass it in, but I need all the stdio functions that normally works on a `FILE*` to work on what I pass in, for I don't know which of the functions it calls - definitely `fread`, possibly `fseek` too.
The code is rather a performance-sensitive one, so I would like to avoid writing the buffer to disk just so that I could create a `FILE*` from it by `fopen`. Is there a way to make a `FILE*` that would allow from my buffer in memory? 
Something like `stringstream` in c++?
My code needs to be able to run both on windows and linux.

I've seen quite a few questions where people try to write via `FILE*` to memory. My case is rather a reverse - I need to present the existing buffer as a *readable* `FILE*`.

Thanks a lot!

P.S. yes, [Using a C string like a FILE*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11381694/using-a-c-string-like-a-file) is exactly what I'm asking, somehow I couldn't find it earlier...

Still, if you could suggest a solution on windows, that would be very helpful!

Comment: Which language are you using, `C` or `C++`?

Comment: man fopen to see the api...

Comment: I think the question is similar to this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11381694/using-a-c-string-like-a-file

Comment: Well, POSIX systems can use [`fmemopen`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/fmemopen), but [it doesn't look like any such equivalent exists for Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12249610/364696).

Comment: I don't know of a function in the standard C library that does that, for for POSIX system (linux,mac,bsd) there is [`fmemopen`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fmemopen.3.html)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using a C string like a FILE\*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11381694/using-a-c-string-like-a-file)

Comment: Does Windows has something like [`pipe`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/pipe.2.html)? With a pipe and [`fdopen`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/fdopen) you could simulate that on Windows, but you wouldn't be able to do `fseek`.

Comment: If you write a temp file, it shouldn't require writing to (physical) disk.  Sane systems mount a tmpfs on `/tmp`, so you're only using (virtual) memory.

Answer (score 5):

Posix requires the [`fmemopen()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fmemopen.html) function, which does exactly what you ask.

Glibc [certainly has it](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fmemopen.3.html).

Can't say for sure about Windows, but it appears that MinGW includes newlib, which also implements it. If that's any help.

Comment: Possibly worth noting that code equivalent to fmemopen() was/is used in some standard libraries to implement [v]s[n]printf()...